# condition html submit option in NodeJs client

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

My NodeJs Application render html output but I need to pass variable to create different submit option.

This is existing working output

```
<!doctype html>                                                                                                                                                               
<html lang="en">                                                                                                                          
<head>                                                                                                                                                                   
</head>                                                                                                                                   
<div class="middle">                                                                                                                                
  <form action="/myaction" method="POST">                                                   
    <input type="hidden" name="myValue" value="{{newValue}}">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit"> 
  </form>
</div>
```

I like to check if newValue exist (Not Nil) using Javascript or anything better like this
if (newValue) { .. } else { .. }

```
<!doctype html>                                                                                                                                                               
<html lang="en">                                                                                                                          
<head>                                                                                                                                                                   
</head>                                                                                                                                   
<div class="middle">  
  if (newValue) {                                                                                                                    
     <form action="/myaction" method="POST"  onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit?');">
  } else {                                                                                                                                
     <form action="/myaction" method="POST">                                                   
  }
<input type="hidden" name="myValue" value="{{newValue}}">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit"> 
</form>
</div>
```

I have no idea how to use Javascript to check condition in NodeJs environment at client with exist html.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a template library like EJS (or similar)

With EJS you can pass value from the route to the view and perform 'server side' rendering / logic.

Comment: How about that if in html. What I don't understand of the <script> tags ?

Comment: That is essentially what EJS does, it lets you do conditonal logic in the 'view' or .ejs file (this would contain your html code) 
so the concept is two fold. In the response from the route you would pass the (newValue) param, then in your ejs view you do something like <% if (newvalue === 1){%> html code etc etc <%}else{%>other html code<%}> EJS lets you do server side templating with data passed to the view, so it processes before sending to the server

Comment: But this is existing html file., some of the variable already passed, I just add another one for condition. I can not change to dot.ejs.